# Keep hover state on drop down navigation

Tags: navigation

I've got the drop down navigation working in Sharepoint and have styled it so it looks fairly decent, but I was wondering if there was a way to keep the hover state on the top navigation bar when you're hovering the items, for example http://www.hamiltonisland.com.au/ ?

Any help would be much appareciated, thank you!

Comment: Could you try to better articulate what you're looking for? Out of the box, SharePoint navigation should remain "hovered" as long as you're hovering.

Comment: Basically when you hover the top item, the state changes, but I'd like for it to retain that state when I'm actually hovering the items in the navigation, if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

The script toggles the element between the "hover" and "hover-off" class.  You may need to tweak it to be more specific with the selector, but I just tested it and it does what you want:

```
   .menu li.hover {
       background:Red;
   }
```

Comment: Oh, and my assumption was that this is SP 2010.

Comment: Okay, wow - so simple yet this works perfectly! Thank you.

Comment: God damn. When I click the tick, nothing happens, when I click vote up it says I don't have enough reputation... :/

Comment: Nick, glad it worked for you.  just mark it as answered.